# Sinon spy expect function invocation within nested function

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, sinon, chai

How can I use Sinon spy to check that an imported class function is called from within a function inside the current class? I am trying to invoke the `.calledOnce` method on the imported class function but only if it's invoked within its function container.

An example is illustrated as follows:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
// foo.js
class foo {
    static fooFn() {

    }
}

// bar.js
import foo from 'foo';

class bar {
    barFn() {
        foo.fooFn()
    }
}

// barTest.js
import { expect, assert } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import bar from 'bar';

describe('barTest', () => {
     beforeEach(function beforeCallback() {
         this.fooSpy = sinon.spy(foo, 'fooFn');
     });

     it('calls foo once', () => {
         bar.barFn();
         expect(foo.fooFn).calledOnce;
     });
});
```

In the above case, I am able to globally spy that `fooFn` is called once. However, I would like to strengthen the expect with a check that `foo.fooFn` is called within `barFn`.

Answer (score 0):

You could verify the caller function using arguments.caller e.g.

```
expect(arguments.caller).equal(bar.barFun);
```